# Как объединить столбцы с переносом на новую строку?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Имею `df` следующего формата:

```
name    1     2    3    4
 AB   12  | none | none | none
 CD  none | rty  | none | none
 df  none | none | gh   | none 
 ZD  none | rg   | none | ty
```

Как можно привести его к следующему виду:

```
name  dscr  
 AB   12  
 CD   rty
 df   gh 
 zd   rg
 zd   ty
```

Нужно "cхлопнуть" последнии колонки `1, 2, 3, 4` в одну, соответственно если встречается несколько значений как в строке `ZD` вынести каждое значение в отдельную строку.

Можно ли как-то универсально сделать это?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
res = (df
       .set_index("name")
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name="dscr")
       .drop(columns="level_1"))
```

результат:

```
In [361]: res
Out[361]:
  name dscr
0   AB   12
1   CD  rty
2   df   gh
3   ZD   rg
4   ZD   ty
```